# Error: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory in Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

When I try to copy a file from server 192.168.180.47 to server 192.168.152.239, I get an error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
user@192.168.152.239: Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

my command for copy file from 47 host in Jenkisn shell command

```
scp /home/app/download/app/application_1.1.tar.gz sshpass -p mypassword user@192.168.152.239:/home/Myapp
```

i tried adding host 47 via ssh-keyscan but it didn't work. Also I reinstalled ssh_askpass but that didn't help either

Comment: Make sure your user has the right to copy a file to the target directory first, i had this issue long time ago !

Comment: Strange syntax you use. Try this: `sshpass -p mypassword scp /home/app/download/app/application_1.1.tar.gz user@192.168.152.239:/home/Myapp`

Comment: How can i do this ? I do not know anything at all about access rights and how they are configured.